# Correct usage of "was passed"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, word-usage, tenses

Recently I came across a phrase that sounds wrong to me as a native speaker (New Zealand English), but I can't find a rule that explains whether this is correct or not.

> "The submitted build was passed."

The context of this statement is in submitting code to a build server, which runs tests on the code and the outcome is a pass or a fail.

I naturally want to correct it to "the submitted build passed", or "the submitted build has passed".

I know that "he was passed by another pedestrian" is correct, but I don't understand what about the above sentence makes me think it is incorrect.

Is this correct English? Which rule explains why it is correct or incorrect?

Comment: It’s a passive construction of what I would say is an [unaccusative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unaccusative_verb#Unaccusativity_in_English) verb, which I agree doesn’t really make sense. “The law was passed by the assembly” just about makes sense (here _pass_ means _ratify_ or similar), but who ‘passes’ a build? Ultimately, whether a verb can function unaccusatively or transitively, and in what sense(s), is just a property of that particular verb – I don’t think there are any ‘rules’ that determine it. It may be that _pass_ in this sense does function as a transitive verb to some.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet the continuous integration environment passes a build (i.e. runs all the tests). She is queen of her domain. By royal assent doth the build pass into production.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - ???  "but who ‘passes’ a build".   It is absolutely identical to your "law was passed" example.   You submit a build to the programming team; the team "pass" it - exactly as in your law/assembly example.  (In some cases, the "robot" also approves/passes it.)   BTW Thank goodness there is someone on here who is not a programmer :/

Comment: @Fattie Well, if you submit it to an actual team, then yes, they pass it (or more commonly, they _approve_ it); but that's not the case here. To a certain extent, the build server which runs the tests also ‘passes’ the build here, but seeing it as an actual agent is anthropomorphising it more than most people would normally do. It is far more common to see the unaccusative construction “The build (has) passed”, in the same way that you almost never hear phrases like “She was passed/failed” when referring to exams, but always “She passed/failed (her exam)”.

Comment: Hi @JanusBahsJacquet - for the first time ever, I totally fail to understand what you're saying  :)  Are you drunk?  :)  (1) Simple fact: regarding the specific question, it is totally commonplace - in computing - to say the actual literal words "the build passed" also "that build was passed 10 minutes ago" or perhaps "last night's build was passed just now".  It is totally idiomatic, commonplace, and normal usage in computing.  (2) I'm totally confused by your comment that "the law was passed" as you say "just about" makes sense: "the law was passed" is a commonplace phrase!

Comment: It's just a US / Commonwealth English difference - for speakers of Commonwealth English, information that has current relevance pretty much has to be expressed in a perfect tense, but speakers of US English will use the simple past. This results in something that sounds fundamentally wrong to the rest of us, because by our lights, the simple fact that they are sending the message signals that the information is of current relevance, whereas the choice of tense signals that it is not.

Comment: I get the same reaction every time I get a message that says *your order was processed* or *your email address was removed from the mailing list*.

Answer (score 1):

As a fellow NZ English speaker that looks OK to me. The build was submitted to a system to be tested, and that system gave it a pass mark as a result of the testing.

A more wordy way to say it would be

> The submitted build was passed *by the test system*

or

> The submitted build was given a passing mark by the test system

Answer (score 0):

Here "pass" means precisely "ratify" or "approve".

This meaning of "pass" in computing (ie, "approve", "ratify") is absolutely commonplace in computing.

“The law was passed by the assembly” - for example - is a totally normal, commonplace sentence. "The build was passed by the server" is a totally notmal, commonplace sentence.

There is perhaps some confusion about the past tense of "was"?

When a build gets passed by, say, Apple's TestFlight cloud servers it can only be .. in the past, if you see what I mean.  Because it's an instantaneous process.  (There's an annoying delay before it happens, then it happens "straight away" - it can't really "be happening".)  Perhaps for that reason it's totally normal to talk about it in the past - "phew, it took three hours but the build was finally passed by TestFlight".  "The build was passed at last, hooray!"

Comment: Cross-posting with my comment above, “the brakes passed” and “the student passed” are examples of the unaccusative construction, which the asker (and I) _would_ expect to find. “The brakes were passed” and “the student was passed” would be passive constructions equivalent to the one in the question, and they sound just as unusual to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - you're right, those last two examples don't include the "was" as per the discussion here; my bad.